# Extract all files named datewise belong to specific time period using Python

Tags: python, csv

Suppose we have 30 files in a folder such that
1234567_val_2022-02-01.csv 1234567_train_2022-02-01.csv 1234567_test_2022-02-01.csv 1234567_val_2022-02-02.csv 1234567_train_2022-02-02.csv 1234567_test_2022-02-02.csv 1234567_val_2022-02-03.csv 1234567_train_2022-02-03.csv 1234567_test_2022-02-03.csv 1234567_val_2022-02-04.csv 1234567_train_2022-02-04.csv 1234567_test_2022-02-04.csv 1234567_val_2022-02-05.csv 1234567_train_2022-02-05.csv 1234567_test_2022-02-05.csv 1234568_val_2022-02-01.csv 1234568_train_2022-02-01.csv 1234568_test_2022-02-01.csv  1234568_val_2022-02-02.csv 1234568_train_2022-02-02.csv 1234568_test_2022-02-02.csv 1234568_val_2022-02-03.csv 1234568_train_2022-02-03.csv 1234568_test_2022-02-03.csv 1234568_val_2022-02-04.csv 1234568_train_2022-02-04.csv 1234568_test_2022-02-04.csv 1234568_val_2022-02-05.csv 1234568_train_2022-02-05.csv 1234568_test_2022-02-05.csv

where first seven characters are 1234567, 1234567.. unique ID and 2022-02-01, 2022-02-02 ..are date in format (%Y%M%D).
How will we list all train, test and val .csv files between 2022-02-01 and 2022-02-03 in python?

output:

train files between  2022-02-01 and 2022-02-03:

1234567_train_2022-02-01.csv
1234567_train_2022-02-02.csv
1234568_train_2022-02-03.csv
1234568_train_2022-02-01.csv
1234568_train_2022-02-02.csv
1234568_train_2022-02-03.csv

test files between  2022-02-01 and 2022-02-03:

1234567_test_2022-02-01.csv
1234567_test_2022-02-02.csv
1234568_test_2022-02-03.csv
1234568_test_2022-02-01.csv
1234568_test_2022-02-02.csv
1234568_test_2022-02-03.csv

val files:

1234567_val_2022-02-01.csv
1234567_val_2022-02-02.csv
1234568_val_2022-02-03.csv
1234568_val_2022-02-01.csv
1234568_val_2022-02-02.csv
1234568_val_2022-02-03.csv

Comment: Loop over the filenames, parse the date, and filter by comparisons to the desired start and end dates. What happened when you tried to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach could be to extract the date from the filename, parse it by converting it to `datetime.datetime`. We can then iterate over each date and compare with the deadlines.

```
files = [[datetime.datetime.strptime(os.path.splitext(file)[0][-10:], '%Y-%m-%d'), file] for file in os.listdir()]

start = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 3)

for file in files:
    if start <= file[0] <= end:
        print(file[1])
```

---

To retrieve the date, we used [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext). We then kept only the last 10 characters.

---

### To separate files according to their id

```
files = [os.path.splitext(file)[0].split('_') for file in os.listdir()]

start = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 3)

valid_files = {}
for file in files:
    if start <= datetime.datetime.strptime(file[-1], '%Y-%m-%d') <= end:
        filename = "_".join(file) + ".csv"
        if file[1] in valid_files:
            valid_files[file[1]].append(filename)
        else:
            valid_files[file[1]] = [filename]
print(valid_files)
```

**Output:**

```
{
    'val': ['1234567_val_2022-02-01.csv', '1234567_val_2022-02-02.csv', '1234567_val_2022-02-03.csv', '1234568_val_2022-02-01.csv', '1234568_val_2022-02-02.csv', '1234568_val_2022-02-03.csv'],
    'train': ['1234567_train_2022-02-01.csv', '1234567_train_2022-02-02.csv', '1234567_train_2022-02-03.csv', '1234568_train_2022-02-01.csv', '1234568_train_2022-02-02.csv', '1234568_train_2022-02-03.csv'],
    'test': ['1234567_test_2022-02-01.csv', '1234567_test_2022-02-02.csv', '1234567_test_2022-02-03.csv', '1234568_test_2022-02-01.csv', '1234568_test_2022-02-02.csv', '1234568_test_2022-02-03.csv']
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use parse (https://pypi.org/project/parse/)

```
import parse

name = "1234567_train_2022-02-01.csv"
result = parse.parse("{}_{}_{}-{}-{}.csv", name)
print(result)
if result[2] == '2022' and result[3] == '02' and result[4] >= '01' and result[4] <= '03':
   # do something
```